# Need help making this small javascript 'game'

Tags: javascript

Trying to use javascript to make a game/script that:
- each number from 0-20 equal a specific word. Ex: 0=saw, 1=tie, 2=noah.
- a number pops up on the screen and the user needs to type in the word that = that number.
- Then the program says if I was correct or not and adds to my points.

Comment: Where's your code so far? A jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: Hmm, looks like mnemonic peg words. Go to: http://www.flashcardexchange.com/cards/peg-words-238153 and click "study." (Or make your own flash cards^^) You get your score at the end.

Answer (score 2):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/gfQsP/

```
var points = 0;
function game() {
    var words = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur adipisci elit'.split(' ');
    var rand = -~(Math.random() * words.length);
    var result = prompt('Word number '+ rand +'?');
    var match = words[rand-1] === result.toLowerCase();
    alert( match ? 'Good' : 'Bad');
    match && points++;
}
```

Comment: -1 because you couldn't do it in one line... (Not really; +1.)

Answer (score 0):

well this can be easy:

just make a object containing key value pairs like this:

```
var obj = {
key1: value1,
key2: value2
};
```

Then ask the player the value of particular number. Loop through this object to scan the value of that particular number to match the value as entered by the player. if found increment the points counter.

Its pretty straight forward.

Comment: Given words numbered sequentially from 0-20, why wouldn't you use an array with the words in it?